# Converting code from jQuery to JavaScript doesn't get the same result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code in jQuery :

```
        setTimeout(function () {

                $('body .animate-box.item-animate').each(function (k) {
                    var el = $(this);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var effect = el.data('animate-effect');
                        if (effect === 'fadeIn') {
                            el.addClass('fadeIn animated-fast');
                        } else if (effect === 'fadeInLeft') {
                            el.addClass('fadeInLeft animated-fast');
                        } else if (effect === 'fadeInRight') {
                            el.addClass('fadeInRight animated-fast');
                        } else {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated-fast');
                        }

                        el.removeClass('item-animate');
                    }, k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo');
                });

            }, 100);
```

I've tried to rewrite it using vanilla JS, but I don't get the same result. The value of the `el` element is different and this makes my web page refresh one time.

This is the code in JavaScript:

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            var index = 0;
            document.querySelectorAll('body, .animate-box.item-animate').forEach( (k) => {
                var el = k;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var effect = el.dataset.animateEffect;

                    if (effect === 'fadeIn') {
                        el.classList.add('fadeIn', 'animated-fast');
                    } else if (effect === 'fadeInLeft') {
                        el.classList.add('fadeInLeft', 'animated-fast');
                    } else if (effect === 'fadeInRight') {
                        el.classList.add('fadeInRight', 'animated-fast');
                    } else {
                        el.classList.add('fadeInUp', 'animated-fast');
                    }

                    el.classList.remove('item-animate');
                }, ++index * 200);
            });
        }, 100);
```

Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the comma in `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Suggestion: Those `if` clauses can be reduced to `el.classList.add(['fadeIn', 'fadeInLeft', 'fadeInRight', 'fadeInUp'].includes(el.dataset.animateEffect) ? el.dataset.animateEffect : 'fadeInUp', 'animated-fast');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct conversion of this:

```
 $('body .animate-box.item-animate')
```

should be this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body .animate-box.item-animate')
```

and not this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body, .animate-box.item-animate')
```

**Explanation**

This `document.querySelectorAll('body, .animate-box.item-animate')` will return all `body` elements (which are just one per page) and all elements which as the class `animate-box.item-animate`.

This `document.querySelectorAll('body .animate-box.item-animate')` will return all elements that are inside of the body element, which as the class `animate-box.item-animate`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that :)

Comment: @user3063909 If you believe that is the correct answer, please accept it! Thank you!

Comment: done! couldn't accept it right away because of the time interval that needed to pass after I posted the question :)